# Do these metamagic options function by RAW?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, metamagic

Yeah I need a list to help me unravel [this abomination](https://forums.giantitp.com/showsinglepost.php?p=12140073&postcount=18), found in the spoiler dropdown.

> Uber Damage
> Spell fusion: Lesser Orb of Acid (1d6/level-> 9d6)
> Metamagic applied: Energy Substitution-> force
> Braid spell + Twin Spell + Dual Spell (base spell X 16)
> Heighten Spell (goes from level 1 to level 9)
> Elemental Lattice (ES-> force) 9d8 + Acid Lattice (ES-> Force) 9d6 + Lightning Lattice (ES-> force) 9d6 + Thunder Lattice (ES-> force) 9d6 + Unholy Lattice 9d8 (targeted creature(s) that are good take -2 on saving throws against this spell) + Ice Lattice (ES-> force) 9d6 + Chaos Lattice 9d8 (-2 to lawful creatures) (72 dice base)
> Empower + Enervate + Exaggerate: multiply total damage dice by 1.5 two times, +3 targets, +3 damage/die. (162 after EEE base) after total spell multipliers (162*16) 2592 total dice of damage which through exaggerate grants a bonus of 7776 damage in first casting.
> Base Damage: (27d8 + 30d6)*1.5*1.5=> 61d8+67d6=>590, after all multipliers (890*16)=14240
> Maximize + Corrupt + Violate + Forceful + Quicken Spell (Half the damage is negative energy, half vile, all forceful)
> Repeat Spell + Echo Spell*
> Initial round damage=22016 vile unholy force damage. Forceful metamagic feat causes the affected creature to be knocked prone if failing the DC of the spell (29).
> Repeat spell recasts the spell in whole automatically (including all applied metamagic feats), Echo spell stores a recasting of the entire spell to be recast later without usage of a higher spell level.
> Total damage from one casting is 44032, each casting grants two echoes of the spell. Each echo cast grants two new echoes.
> Initial usage’s total rounds to rest 8 mins. There after none for all subsequent uses through Echo Spell. Because the spell is quickened it is a free action to cast with the Echo spell.

This lists a number of metamagics I didn't even know existed I want to make sure that this functions by RAW, so does this work?

Comment: The text you've quoted doesn't appear to show up in the page you linked. Is there another page you meant to link to instead?

Comment: Its there just real far down. Check for Xtomjames first post and look in the spoiler.

Comment: @doppelgreener here's the link https://forums.giantitp.com/showsinglepost.php?p=12140073&postcount=18

Comment: Thanks! I've updated with a clearer reference.

Comment: As written this is off topic as a recommendation question, but it can be made on topic by rephrasing as something like "What are the official sources containing metamagic options" would be in topic.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov It is not, and is fine as-is.

Comment: @KRyan Alternatively we could just rephrase it as something like "does this work", either way, your answer addresses the question nicely.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov And that pulls the rug out from under minnmass, who had a perfectly reasonable answer to a good-enough question.

Comment: @KRyan I thought the question was off topic before, so naturally I'm not too worried about that.

Comment: @KRyan this is a better question, resolving an X/Y issue that I didn't notice properly. Thanks for thinking of me, though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are so many things wrong with that post:

- There is no way for a player to “choose” to have a divine rank. No class or other feature allows player access to those rules.
- “Arcane swordsage” isn’t a real class, it’s a suggestion of one idea that a DM could choose to flesh out into a class. It isn’t usable as-is.
- Energy Substitution cannot choose force damage.
- Braid Spell, Exaggerate Spell, and the various Lattice feats appear to be from *Feats* by third-party publisher Alderac Entertainment Group (AEG).¹ They aren’t official parts of D&D 3.5e, and while it is certainly possible that a given table might be using that sourcebook, it is rather a stretch for this poster to assume it.

Of the things that actually, officially exist,

- Empower Spell and Maximize Spell are core.
- Corrupt Spell and Violate Spell are from *Book of Vile Darkness*.
- Energy Substitution and Repeat Spell are from *Deities & Demigods*, which means it’s also in the SRD.
- Enervate Spell is from *Libris Mortis*.¹
- Echoing Spell (which I presume is what is intended by “Echo Spell”) is from *Secrets of Xen’drik*.
- Forceful Spell is from *Dragon* vol. 358.¹

Finally, the claim that

> Yeah, thus far none of these are legal or get you "infinite" damage. However I can get you pretty close.

is wrong—the very first reply mentions the 1d2 crusader, who can in fact deal infinite damage. In fact, theoretical optimization attempts at world record damage usually struggle to *not* go infinite, since infinite damage doesn’t qualify for the record. The concept of “close” to infinite is properly undefined, but the damage this approach promises is not all that impressive in the grand scheme of things. The world record, for reference, is a number so large that if you could write a numeral in a single atom, you would run out of atoms in the known universe long before you finished writing the number—*even in scientific notation!* Using [Knuth’s up arrow notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation), the world record damage is (2.5×10↑36530)↑↑73600 damage. Sadly, the thread describing it seems to have been lost to one of Wizards’ many forum reboots. We do have [a copy preserving the opening post and final result](http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=6571.0),² but some improvements between the two are referenced but not explained in the final post, leaving some holes in the explanation.

---

1. <sub>With thanks to HeyICanChan for the sources of Braid Spell, Enervate Spell, Exaggerate Spell, Forceful Spell, and the various Lattices.</sub>
2. <sub>With thanks to Drejzer for finding this link.</sub>

Comment: You could use simulacrum cheese with the god of beggars (Erbin?). I'm pretty sure he has stats, to gain divine ranks(assuming simulacrum have Divine ranks). Just have all your sims invest one in you. But yes the lattice and whatnot does appear to be homebrew.

Comment: Enervate Spell (*Libris Mortis* 26) and Forceful Spell (*Dragon* #358 87) exist officially. I think Braid Spell, Exaggerate Spell, and the Lattices are from AEG's [*Feats*](https://www.amazon.com/Feats-Fantasy-Roleplaying-Alderac-Staff/dp/1887953736).

Comment: "There is no feat or spell called anything Lattice. Exaggerate Spell isn’t a thing either." Have you checked all the issues of Dragon magazine? There can be some pretty obscure stuff tucked away in one issue or another.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Huh, good catches. Thanks.

Comment: I think I found a "mirror" of said post: http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=6571.0

Comment: @Drejzer Yup, that’s it, though it only captures two posts out of a lengthy thread. The two most important, but still, we’re missing a lot of detail.